# React map() is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Not to sure why I am getting an error with mapping over this. but here is what my code looks like:

```
  const [allTestTypes, setAllTestTypes] = useState('')
       {!level ?  null : allTestTypes.map((item =>
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>{configs[level].name}:</div>
              <DropdownSingle 
                name={configs[level].name} 
                value={testType} 
                options={configs[level].dropdownValues} 
                onChange={onTestFieldUpdate}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
        ))

   }
```

and here is the response from what I am trying to map over:
[image]

error updated:
[image]

Comment: what is `setAllTestTypes`

Comment: updated @DanielA.White

Comment: i think you want to use `allTestTypes` instead.

Comment: Piggybacking off of what @Daniel A. White mentioned, you probably want to loop over `allTestTypes` because with React hooks `setAllTestTypes` is just going to be a function that you would use to set the data to the `allTestTypes` array.

Comment: thanks guys, however i am still getting the same error but with allTestTypes now. I have just updated the question

Comment: You're initializing it with an empty string. What about an empty array since you want to `map` it?

Comment: interesting, still got the same error    const [allTestTypes, setAllTestTypes] = useState([]) if thats correct

Comment: what is the exact data you want to map because the response you have included is of type object with two arrays inside? so if you are directly assigning it to `allTestTypes` then you cannot map over it. So can you please include more code?

Comment: @SagarDarekar its the test_type value I have put a screen shot on what needs to be mapped over in the question. I believe it is an array and an object. Would you use .keys in this case?

Comment: ok then if you initialize with array then nothing is wrong with your code. One thing you can do, just create a new array with useState try mapping on it with other jsx and conditions removed.